# Select last known assignment but only for the latest person

Tags: mysql

I have been working on this query for a table lookup for hours and I am finally calling in for help to SO.

There are three tables:

- computer (assetTag for ID, other information about a computer)
- student  (studentID for ID, other student information)
- assignment (studentID, assetTag, issueDate)

These are obviously linked as a many to many using assignment like a junction table:
Student <-> assignment <-> computer

I put together a query to show a list of student names, and the last computer assignment they had.  The query works great except for one problem I can't wrap my head around.  If studentA is assigned computer 10000 and then turns it in, and then that computer is assigned to studentB until the end of the year when they turned it in, looking up that asset shows both students as the rightful owners of the machine.  I need it to only show the latest student.

Current query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS s.studentID, s.lName, s.fName, s.uName, s.grade, c.assetTag, c.location, c.`status`  FROM student s 
INNER JOIN
(
        SELECT studentID, MAX(issueDate) MaxDate
        FROM assignment GROUP BY studentID
)   MaxDates ON s.studentID = MaxDates.studentID AND s.active = 1 
INNER JOIN assignment a ON MaxDates.studentID = a.studentID AND MaxDates.MaxDate = a.issueDate AND a.loaner = 0
INNER JOIN computer c ON a.assetTag = c.assetTag
```

For the most part previous owners of a machine are inactive (s.active = 0) so there aren't very many duplicates but there shouldn't be any duplicate assetTags.

I wish I could aggregate assetTags based off the last assignment EVER.

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I need to get this done pretty fast.

**EDIT:**
It may help if I explain that there are MANY students to MANY computers and MANY computers to MANY students.

Throughout the year a student may change computers repeatedly and a computer may change to different students repeatedly.

Comment: Where?  I am sorry but I'm confused where to use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery could look like this:

```
SELECT studentID, issueDate MaxDate
FROM assignment
GROUP BY studentID
HAVING issueDate = max(issueDate)
```

This will return a list of studentIDs with each student's most recent assignment.

As an alternative, you can replace your entire mess of a query with:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS s.studentID, s.lName, s.fName, s.uName, s.grade, c.assetTag, c.location, c.`status`, a.issueDate
  from assignment a
 inner join student s on a.studentID = s.studentID
 inner join computer c on a.assetTag = c.assetTag
 group by a.assetTag
having a.issueDate = max(a.issueDate)
```

Updated since `having` doesn't work like that:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS s.studentID, s.lName, s.fName, s.uName, s.grade, c.assetTag, c.location, c.`status`, a.issueDate 
from assignment a 
inner join student s on a.studentID = s.studentID 
inner join computer c on a.assetTag = c.assetTag 
where a.issueDate = (select max(issueDate) from assignment where assetTag=a.assetTag)
group by a.assetTag
```

Comment: This subquery doesn't return all of the results needed.  My subquery returns 3289 results, this one only returns 1016.  I honestly have no clue why. -Edit- so the resulting query ends up only giving me 400 students and their assignments as opposed to 1600 (which is my usual return)

Comment: I've amended my answer with what I hope is a replacement for the entire query

Comment: This gives me: /* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'a.issueDate' in 'having clause' */

Comment: Hey I copied that from the schema you posted. If that column doesn't actually exist, please update your question.

Comment: LOL.  The column absolutely exists.  Your subquery doesn't return enough results and the overall query has that error and I don't know why.  I don't think you are seeing the problem.  My original query returns each student and their respective assignment.  The problem lies with two students that have a claim to the same asset through two different assignments and both students are active again.

Comment: Ah, you need to add `a.issueDate` to the list of select'ed columns. Columns in the `having` clause must also exist in `select`. Updated the query in the asnwer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34171/discussion-between-bil1-and-joe-frambach)

Comment: After much discussion and testing we have a winner.  Thank you!